# Date range not working properly, specifically the to, function I think

Tags: php

The date range picker won't work properly in my inventory report, but for the sales report it works properly.

E.g. From *2018-03-07* to *2018-03-08*, the *2018-03-08* does not show in the report.

Picture of the report:
[image: Picture of the report]

Here is my code

```
<head>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
  // Write on keyup event of keyword input element
  $("#searchme").keyup(function(){
    // When value of the input is not blank
    if( $(this).val() != "")
    {
      // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
      $("#searchTbl tbody>tr").hide();
      $("#searchTbl td:contains-ci('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent("tr").show();
    }
    else
    {
      // When there is no input or clean again, show everything back
      $("#searchTbl tbody>tr").show();
    }
  });
});
// jQuery expression for case-insensitive filter
$.extend($.expr[":"], 
{
    "contains-ci": function(elem, i, match, array) 
  {
    return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
  }
});
</script>
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>

<?php include('session.php'); ?>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<?php include('navbar.php'); ?>



<style>
.logo1 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 45%;
    font-family: ""Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace";
    top: 0%;
    width: 80%;
    background-color:#F8F8FF;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;

}
h3{
  font-size:20px;
    font-family: "Arial";

}

table {
    width:60%;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
@media print {
  @page { margin: 0; }
  body { margin: 1cm; }

  #printPageButton {
    display: none;
  }
  #e{
    display:none;
  }
    .footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    font-family: ""Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace";
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#F8F8FF;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

}
</style>




<?php
if(isset($_POST['salesbtn'])) {
$from=$_POST['dayfrom'];
$to=$_POST['dayto'];
?>


</head>
<body>



<div style="height:50px;"></div>
<div id="page-wrapper">

  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-0">


  <br><img src="../upload/logo.jpg"  class="logo1" style="height:50px; width:50px;" ><br>
<center><h1>Inventory Report</h1><h3>  From (<?php echo $from; ?>) To (<?php echo $to; ?>)</h3>
<br>
<button id="printPageButton" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="window.print();">Print</button>
  <button id="e" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="goBack()">Back</button>
  <br><br>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Arial Narrow, Arial,sans-serif; font-size:15px;" border="1">
      <tr>
      <th width="25%"><div align="center"><strong> Date  </strong></div></th>
           <th width="20%"><div align="center"><strong> User</strong></div></th>
        <th width="20%"><div align="center"><strong>Action</strong></div></th>
           <th width="20%"><div align="center"><strong>Product Name</strong></div></th>
    <th width="20%"><div align="center"><strong>Quantity </strong></div></th>
      </tr> 

        <?php
          $iq=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from inventory left join product on product.productid=inventory.productid where inventory_date BETWEEN CAST('$from' AS DATE) AND CAST('$to' AS DATE) order by inventory_date desc ");
          while($iqrow=mysqli_fetch_array($iq)){


          ?>
            <tr>
              <td class="hidden"></td>
              <td><?php echo date('M d, Y h:i A',strtotime($iqrow['inventory_date'])); ?></td>  
              <td>
              <?php 
                $u=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `user` left join customer on customer.userid=user.userid left join supplier on supplier.userid=user.userid where user.userid='".$iqrow['userid']."'");
                $urow=mysqli_fetch_array($u);
                if($urow['access']==1){
                  echo "Admin";
                }
                elseif($urow['access']==2){
                  echo $urow['customer_name'];
                }
                else{
                  echo $urow['company_name'];
                }
              ?>
              </td>
              <td align="right"><?php echo $iqrow['action']; ?></td>
              <td align="right"><?php echo $iqrow['product_name']; ?></td>
              <td align="right"><?php echo $iqrow['quantity']; ?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php
 }         }
        ?>

</tr> </td>


</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php include('script.php'); ?>
<?php include('modal.php'); ?>
<?php include('add_modal.php'); ?>
<script src="custom.js"></script>
```

EDITED:

This is my inventory.php
In here the user can input the range date from , to .
I dont know if this will help you guys.
I just want to know why it does not work well.
The problem is when i input 2018-03-08 - 2018-03-08 , the march 7 shows up but the march 8 wont show up.

```
 <form action="total_inventory.php" method="post">
  From: <input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="E.G.(2018-01-14)" name="dayfrom" required pattern="[0-9]{4}+[0-9]+[0-9]"> To: <input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="E.G.(2018-02-11)" name="dayto" required pattern="[0-9]{4}+[0-9]+[0-9]">
  <input type="submit" value="Show Report" name="salesbtn" ></form>
```

EDITED:

Here is my inventory table
[INVENTORY DATA TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cicNl.jpg)

UPDATED: 
This is the output , still does not show the transaction from march 7
[Sample Updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuKF4.jpg)

Comment: You mean to say your data is not properly bind right?

Comment: There's no input tag in your html code that has class datepicker. The datepicker code won't attach to anything.

Comment: Put your `datepicker js` code inside  `$(document).ready(function(){` so that it will be executed only when jquery and the page are already loaded.

Comment: your question is not clear,we need some more details to hep you.kindly update your question with some description and code

Comment: echo your $from and $to in action page and check if dates are coming right

Comment: tried echo , the date is right

Comment: Try this query : `"select * from inventory left join product on product.productid=inventory.productid where inventory_date BETWEEN DATE('$from') AND DATE('$to') order by inventory_date desc "`

Comment: B. Desai still does not work

Comment: Try this: `select * from inventory left join product on product.productid=inventory.productid where  DATE(inventory_date) BETWEEN DATE('$from') AND DATE('$to') order by inventory_date desc`

Comment: Thank you Desai , it worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is time also in your table so you have to search with time. means your from should be `d-m-Y 00:00:01` and your to should be `d-m-Y 23:59:59`

Updated : concat your date variables like this.

```
// Assume `$_POST['dayfrom'] = 03/15/2018;`
// Assume `$_POST['dayto'] = 03/31/2018;`

$from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['dayfrom']))." 00:00:01";
$to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['dayto']))." 23:59:59";

echo $from; // if date is `03/15/2018` output like `2018-03-15 00:00:01`
echo $to; // if date is `03/31/2018` output like `2018-03-31 23:59:59`

// NOTE: check your date format is like this or not, then run the SQL query.
```

Updated Query:

```
$iq=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from inventory left join product on product.productid=inventory.productid where ( inventory_date BETWEEN CAST('$from' AS DATE) AND CAST('$to' AS DATE) ) order by inventory_date desc ");
```

Comment: What is the value in you `inventory_date ` column? update some records from you `inventory` table into question.

Comment: It work for the user module , but for my admin module it didnt work , they have the same problem but for the user module it works fine

Comment: I update the query. may be condition getting wrong in query.

Comment: what is the output of `echo $iq; exit();` ??

Comment: the output is still the same

Comment: Sir Vipul I added the output in my post

Comment: put this `echo $iq; exit();` after `$iq=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from inventory left join product on product.productid=inventory.productid where inventory_date BETWEEN CAST('$from' AS DATE) AND CAST('$to' AS DATE) order by inventory_date desc ");` **I want to know whats the query is running**  this `echo $iq;` print your query.